# Android GoogleTV display interaction from background process

Tags: android, background-process, google-tv

I was wondering if it is possible inthe Android GoogleTV model to have a background process that interacts with the display.

Can I display some sort of notifications on the screen when the user is watching video or engaging in a different app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to display a Toast message. Otherwise you can't. Status Bar messages won't be displayed until you return to Home.

Comment: BTW - I created an App w/ a translucent background and ran it on a box and couldn't get the video to be visible as home was underneath.  You might be able to send Home some intent to get it to hide itself, but I didn't try that.